# replace root element of xml file in python

Tags: python, xml

I have xml like this

```
<ns0:REQUEST xmlns:ns0:="http://www.sss.com/request-response">
  .......
  .......
</ns0:REQUEST>
```

where the REQUEST is the root element of xml - my question is how to replace this line to be like this

```
<ns0:REQUEST xmlns:ns0:="http://www.sss.com/request-response" 
               xsi:schemaLocation:"http://www.sss.com/schema_V1_1_1.xsd">
  .......
  .......
</ns0:REQUEST>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the raw XML? Dirty way: `a=YOUR_XML; a.replace('request-response"', 'request-response" xsi:schemaLocation:"http://www.sss.com/schema_V1_1_1.xsd"')`

Comment: Neither of this seems to be valid xml

Comment: schemaLocation value must include the namespace followed by the location; `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sss.com/request-response http://www.sss.com/schema_V1_1_1.xsd"`